# Finding unique tuples in R but ignoring order

Tags: r, unique

Since my data is much more complicated, I made a smaller sample dataset (I left the reshape in to show how I generated the data).

```
set.seed(7)
x = rep(seq(2010,2014,1), each=4)
y = rep(seq(1,4,1), 5)
z = matrix(replicate(5, sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"))))
temp_df = cbind.data.frame(x,y,z)
colnames(temp_df) = c("Year", "Rank", "ID")
head(temp_df)
require(reshape2)
dcast(temp_df, Year ~ Rank)
```

which results in...

```
> dcast(temp_df, Year ~ Rank)
Using ID as value column: use value.var to override.
  Year 1 2 3 4
1 2010 D B A C
2 2011 A C D B
3 2012 A B D C
4 2013 D A C B
5 2014 C A B D
```

Now I essentially want to use a function like unique, but ignoring order to find where the first 3 elements are unique.

Thus in this case:

I would have A,B,C in row 5

I would have A,B,D in rows 1&3

I would have A,C,D in rows 2&4

Also I need counts of these "unique" events

Also 2 more things.  First, my values are strings, and I need to leave them as strings.
Second, if possible, I would have a column between year and 1 called Weighting, and then when counting these unique combinations I would include each's weighting.  This isn't as important because all weightings will be small positive integer values, so I can potentially duplicate the rows earlier to account for weighting, and then tabulate unique pairs.

Comment: you should use `set.seed` for reproducibility http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Whoops that is the effect of my sleep deprivation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df <- dcast(temp_df, Year ~ Rank)

combos <- apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))

combos
#     1     2     3     4     5 
# "BCD" "ABC" "ACD" "BCD" "ABC"
```

For each row of the data frame, the values in columns 1, 2, and 3 (as labeled in the post) are sorted using `sort`, then concatenated using `paste0`. Since order doesn't matter, this ensures that identical cases are labeled consistently.

Note that the `paste0` function is equivalent to `paste(..., sep = "")`. The `collapse` argument says to concatenate the values of a vector into a single string, with vector values separated by the value passed to `collapse`. In this case, we're setting `collapse = ""`, which means there will be no separation between values, resulting in `"ABC"`, `"ACD"`, etc.

Then you can get the count of each combination using `table`:

```
table(combos)
# ABC ACD BCD 
#   2   1   2
```

Comment: This works perfectly, can you walk me through the `paste0(sort(x), collapse = "")` a little, because this of course isn't my real data, and the data strings are much longer.  I know what paste is, but not paste0, also does collapse remove the quotes between the name?

Comment: @qwertylpc: Glad to hear it works for you. I added some explanation. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same solution as @Alex_A but using tidyverse functions:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df <- dcast(temp_df, Year ~ Rank)

distinct(df, ID = pmap_chr(select(df, num_range("", 1:3)), 
                           ~paste0(sort(c(...)), collapse="")))
```